# script language for flash and c++?

Tags: c++, flash, scripting

I spend hours every week coding my own personal projects.
I have a nice C++ backend. For my next idea, it is small and lite enough to be done in flash. But i want to do it in a scripting language so i can call the code in my C++ projects. What script can i use in flash along with c++?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html), ActionScript is based on ECMAScript (aka JavaScript), so in principle you could write your code in ECMAScript and use an ECMAScript engine for C++. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) has a good list of engine implementations.